# how to add column and how to which data type will be use

Tags: oracle11g

```
s_no    s_name       s_father
-------------------------------
1       ram          mohan
2       hareesh      galla
3       praveen      nagaraj
4       mallikarju   bandaru
5       yashas       penubakam
```

Now I want add DOB column to existing table. How can a DOB column be added into existing table and which data type should be used?

Comment: DOB as in Date Of Birth ? `alter table T1 add DOB date;`

Comment: while declaring date which data type should be use....

Comment: `date` is the data type.

Comment: i don't know which data type to be used for declaring a DOB.

Comment: if i declare date data type...then which format should be give input ..please give example

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
SQL> create table t1 (id number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into t1 values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from t1;

        ID
----------
         1

SQL> alter table t1 add update_date date;

Table altered.

SQL> desc t1
 Name             Null?    Type
 ------------------------ -------- 

 ID                        NUMBER
 UPDATE_DATE               DATE

SQL> update t1 set update_date = to_date('01/01/2013','dd/mm/yyyy');

1 row updated.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from t1;

        ID UPDATE_DATE
---------- -------------------
         1 01/01/2013 00:00:00

SQL> select id , update_date , to_char(update_date , 'dd-MON-yyyy') as formated_update_date from t1;

        ID UPDATE_DATE         FORMATED_UP
---------- ------------------- -----------
         1 01/01/2013 00:00:00 01-JAN-2013
```

I strongly suggest going over the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i1847)